# React Native Execute a Function on State Change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am wanting to fire a function when state changes in my app. I have a modal with a button that changes state.

My home component (edited)

```
...
constructor(props) {
super(props);
  this.state = {
    color:'red',
    modalVisible: false,
  }
}
...
render() {
 return (
  <View>

      <Modal
         animationType={"slide"}
         transparent={false}
         visible={this.state.modalVisible}
      >
       <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({color:'blue'})}>
          <Text>Blue</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setModalVisible(false)}>
          <Text>Blue</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    </Modal>

   <Text style={{color:this.state.color}}>
     Foo
   </Text>
  </View>
 )
 ...
```

However when I close the modal, the color of my text is not changed to blue. It stays red until I open the modal back up, and then close again. Its like the state of 'color' is not being updated. I have ran into this before using redux and 'componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)' but this has stumped me being in the same component.

I am using the native modal component from the docs. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code to show how your two snippets are related?

Comment: I edited my code to reflect how they are related.

Comment: Have you looked at the [link](https://rnplay.org/apps/fDGs3A) in @fumi_hwh's answer? Seems to work to me. If it doesn't help you solve the problem, try to create a runnable example in [rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org) that reproduces your problem. (Edit: [Modified his example](https://rnplay.org/apps/rKeOYg) to be a bit more like yours.)

Comment: have you solution for it? i have same queston. example is emty page.

Comment: Being 3 years since I asked the question, I can say I didn't fully understand the react lifecycle when I asked this. I would now recommend using the `useEffect` hook in react hooks. This will allow you to update state/call functions whenever a piece of state changes that you define. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score -1):

Touchable? TouchableHighlight?

I have not found any problem in your code except TouchaleHighlight tag.

https://rnplay.org/apps/fDGs3A